# Center Div and Javascript Tooltip problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I am using the javascript tooltips called [EZPZ tooltips](http://theezpzway.com/2009/3/17/jquery-plugin-ezpz-tooltip). Here is the [demo](http://theezpzway.com/demos/ezpz-tooltip) page of EZPZ tooltips.

I have this kind of layout with html and css.

The largest div is with position relative with margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; and inside the small box is with position absolute.

[image]

Here is the full code for this html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>The EZPZ Way – EZPZ Tooltip </title>
    <link href="css/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.ezpz_tooltip.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#stay-target-1").ezpz_tooltip({
            contentPosition: 'belowStatic',
            stayOnContent: true,
            offset: 0
        });


    });
</script>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">

    .wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

    h3 { margin-top: 20px; }
    .tooltip-target {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #EEE;
        text-align: center;
        width:100px;
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
        right:100px;
    }
    .tooltip-content {
        display: none;      /* required */
        position: absolute; /* required */
        width: 250px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 3px solid #AF8A31;
        background-color: #FFC848;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
    }
    .tooltip-content p {
        margin: 0;
    }


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="tooltip-target" id="stay-target-1">Stay on Content ToolTip</div>
    <div style="top: 1455px; left: 190px; display: none;" class="stay-tooltip-content tooltip-content" id="stay-content-1">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet enim...<br>
            <a href="javascript:">You can reach down and click this</a>
        </p>
    </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript of EZPZ tooltips.

```
// EZPZ Tooltip v1.0; Copyright (c) 2009 Mike Enriquez, http://theezpzway.com; Released under the MIT License
(function($){
    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.defaults, options);

        return this.each(function(){
            var content = $("#" + getContentId(this.id));
            var targetMousedOver = $(this).mouseover(function(){
                settings.beforeShow(content, $(this));
            }).mousemove(function(e){
                contentInfo = getElementDimensionsAndPosition(content);
                targetInfo = getElementDimensionsAndPosition($(this));
                contentInfo = $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.positions[settings.contentPosition](contentInfo, e.pageX, e.pageY, settings.offset, targetInfo);
                contentInfo = keepInWindow(contentInfo);

                content.css('top', contentInfo['top']);
                content.css('left', contentInfo['left']);

                settings.showContent(content);
            });

            if (settings.stayOnContent && this.id != "") {
                $("#" + this.id + ", #" + getContentId(this.id)).mouseover(function(){
                    content.css('display', 'block');
                }).mouseout(function(){
                    content.css('display', 'none');
                    settings.afterHide();
                });
            }
            else {
                targetMousedOver.mouseout(function(){
                    settings.hideContent(content);
                    settings.afterHide();
                })
            }

        });

        function getContentId(targetId){
            if (settings.contentId == "") {
                var name = targetId.split('-')[0];
                var id = targetId.split('-')[2];
                return name + '-content-' + id;
            }
            else {
                return settings.contentId;
            }
        };

        function getElementDimensionsAndPosition(element){
            var height = element.outerHeight(true);
            var width = element.outerWidth(true);
            var top = $(element).offset().top;
            var left = $(element).offset().left;
            var info = new Array();

            // Set dimensions
            info['height'] = height;
            info['width'] = width;

            // Set position
            info['top'] = top;
            info['left'] = left;

            return info;
        };

        function keepInWindow(contentInfo){
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var output = new Array();

            output = contentInfo;

            if (contentInfo['top'] < windowTop) { // Top edge is too high
                output['top'] = windowTop;
            }
            if ((contentInfo['left'] + contentInfo['width']) > windowWidth) { // Right edge is past the window
                output['left'] = windowWidth - contentInfo['width'];
            }
            if (contentInfo['left'] < 0) { // Left edge is too far left
                output['left'] = 0;
            }

            return output;
        };
    };

    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.positionContent = function(contentInfo, mouseX, mouseY, offset, targetInfo) {
        contentInfo['top'] = mouseY - offset - contentInfo['height'];
        contentInfo['left'] = mouseX + offset;

        return contentInfo;
    };

    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.positions = {
        aboveRightFollow: function(contentInfo, mouseX, mouseY, offset, targetInfo) {
            contentInfo['top'] = mouseY - offset - contentInfo['height'];
            contentInfo['left'] = mouseX + offset;

            return contentInfo;
        }
    };

    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.defaults = {
        contentPosition: 'aboveRightFollow',
        stayOnContent: false,
        offset: 10,
        contentId: "",
        beforeShow: function(content){},
        showContent: function(content){
            content.show();
        },
        hideContent: function(content){
            content.hide();
        },
        afterHide: function(){}
    };

})(jQuery);

// Plugin for different content positions. Keep what you need, remove what you don't need to reduce file size.

(function($){
    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.positions.aboveFollow = function(contentInfo, mouseX, mouseY, offset, targetInfo) {
        contentInfo['top'] = mouseY - offset - contentInfo['height'];
        contentInfo['left'] = mouseX - (contentInfo['width'] / 2);

        return contentInfo;
    };

    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.positions.rightFollow = function(contentInfo, mouseX, mouseY, offset, targetInfo) {
        contentInfo['top'] = mouseY - (contentInfo['height'] / 2);
        contentInfo['left'] = mouseX + offset;

        return contentInfo;
    };

    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.positions.belowRightFollow = function(contentInfo, mouseX, mouseY, offset, targetInfo) {
        contentInfo['top'] = mouseY + offset;
        contentInfo['left'] = mouseX + offset;

        return contentInfo;
    };

    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.positions.belowFollow = function(contentInfo, mouseX, mouseY, offset, targetInfo) {
        contentInfo['top'] = mouseY + offset;
        contentInfo['left'] = mouseX - (contentInfo['width'] / 2);

        return contentInfo;
    };

    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.positions.aboveStatic = function(contentInfo, mouseX, mouseY, offset, targetInfo) {
        contentInfo['top'] = targetInfo['top'] - offset - contentInfo['height'];
        contentInfo['left'] = (targetInfo['left'] + (targetInfo['width'] / 2)) - (contentInfo['width'] / 2);

        return contentInfo;
    };

    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.positions.rightStatic = function(contentInfo, mouseX, mouseY, offset, targetInfo) {
        contentInfo['top'] = (targetInfo['top'] + (targetInfo['height'] / 2)) - (contentInfo['height'] / 2);
        contentInfo['left'] = targetInfo['left'] + targetInfo['width'] + offset;

        return contentInfo;
    };

    $.fn.ezpz_tooltip.positions.belowStatic = function(contentInfo, mouseX, mouseY, offset, targetInfo) {
        contentInfo['top'] = targetInfo['top'] + targetInfo['height'] + offset;
        contentInfo['left'] = (targetInfo['left'] + (targetInfo['width'] / 2)) - (contentInfo['width'] / 2);

        return contentInfo;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

When I hover, the small grey box, tooltips show like this which is wrong.

[image]

But if i remove margin-left: auto; and margin-right:auto; from wrapper class. it works. Here is the actual look that tooltip supposed to be show.

[image]

I think it's somewhere clashed. But i don't know how to fix it. Is there anyway to center the div not using margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; ? I tried with margin:0px auto; and text-align:center also. But it's still occurred same problem with tooltips.

I need the site to be at center and tooltips to be working correctly under hover content also. Please kindly help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`keepInWindow()` is your enemy here by the looks of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gyLpJ/

---

**Edit**: Let's try something easier, welcome tipsy!

Ok. I've always sworn by tipsy plugin for jQuery. It is THE best tooltip plugin, it's so well coded. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/gyLpJ/1/

.. or if you prefer to have the tooltip **HTML** as part of the document and **not in javascript**... try this nifty trick: http://jsfiddle.net/knQvR/2/

Comment: then how can i fix ? commenting keepInWindow() doesn't work :( .. any idea please ?

Comment: Humm, sorry, i think you changed something in html too ? I just noticed that you removed the top and left position for tooltips box ? I exactly replace everything from your side html and javascript. But when i replaced everything with your files, nothing appears at my end. I tested with all the latest browsers, IE9, FF4, chrome 10. But if i add back top and left position of tooltips from html, it works, but it's the same problem that i facing. Tooltips is outside the box, not under the content. Any ideas ?

Comment: sorry my mistake, when i copy everything from your html and javascript, nothing appears because, there's no javascript inside. Now I added and test again, unfortunately, it's still same problem what i am facing. Tooltip  is still display too far with the content. How's on your browser ? Can you please kindly take a screenshot and show me the result. Thank you

Comment: Hi Gary Green, thanks for the tipsy and HTML sample, but the problem is, do you see the link inside the tooltip right ? It's wrote like, you can reach down and click this. That's the one of the reason I chose EZPZ to use this, because when I hover, i can go inside tooltips box and click the link. I need that. But with your example and html tooltips, I can't reach inside the box, once i move it,  tooltip box disappears. Anyway to get it ?

Comment: Ah yes. In my opinion, EZPZ has got it wrong. The whole purpose of tooltips is to give quick useful information, non interactive. If you want something that you can use to click on and interact with, you should look somewhere else away from "tooltips" -- try boxy: http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/